# What is the Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 workload component ID for SQL Server Integration Services Projects SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2022

i'm creating an offline installation for vs22 to use it after withe an Ansible playbook , i'm using this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true) for that .

what i want is to find the workload component ID for SQL Server Integration Services Projects SSIS which you can download it from this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices) as an extension and there is no standalone installation file for it so i can't install it using cmd for example!

this is the CMD i use :

```
vs_enterprise.exe --noweb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeOptional
```

Comment: VS2022 doesn't have yet "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" extension. Microsoft is working on it.

Comment: yes they did i guess ! this is the :https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices it still a preview but it works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS tooling is shipped as a [Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices), not core Visual Studio workload.  So you'll need to install the extension after VS is installed.  See [SSIS Projects extension for VS2022 troubleshooting guide - Offline Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/release-notes-integration-services-2022?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: what about this : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices ?

Comment: Ah, it released while I wasn't looking.  Updated links in answer.

Comment: as @David said the SSIS tooling is an extension not a vs workload ! and i asked this question in first place because i was having a problem installing it using CMD in quite mode so it turned out that the SSIS 0.2 don't support /quiet mode ! 
If any one needs this check this link :  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986614/cmd-installation-in-quiet-mode-keeps-showing-prompt-to-click-install