# CMD installation in quiet mode keeps showing prompt to click install

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, ssis, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to install  Microsoft DataTools IntegrationServices (ssis) for VS 2022 and i want to do it using CMD in quiet mode so it should be automatically !

i tried 2 CMD but i still always see the prompt asks me to click 'install' !

CMD 1:

```
[`start /wait cmd.exe /c C:\Temp\Download\SqlDataTools\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe /INSTALLALL /passive /norestart /log c:\vs2022_ssis.log`][1]
```

CMD 2 :

```
 C:\Temp\Download\SqlDataTools\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe /x /INSTALLALL /quiet /norestart /log c:\vs2022_ssis.log
```

Prompt i get in both CMD :
[image]

Prompt for /? :

[image]

Comment: Did you really use `/quite` or is it a typo? The correct term would be `/quiet` (if the .exe supports it at all - usually installers use `/silent`)

Comment: Yes it's a typo i did use both /quiet and /passive

Comment: Does `Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe /?` tell something useful?

Comment: it don't show anything useful ,i ll add a screen to the question body you can check it

Comment: You sure, `/INSTALLALL` is a valid option? It's not listed.

Comment: yes it is i already used it to install SSDT in vs 2019 ,it's the same as /INSTALL but it install all required options if any are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to use the version 0.1 of SQL Server Integration Services Projects SSIS ([link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/SSIS/vsextensions/MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices/0.1/vspackage))
because i fund out that the 0.2 version don't support /quiet installation for now !

you can check this [Q&A link](https://the%20solution%20was%20to%20use%20the%20version%200.1%20of%20SQL%20Server%20Integration%20Services%20Projects%20SSIS%20(%5Blink%5D%5B1%5D)%20%20becuse%20i%20fund%20out%20that%20the%200.2%20verstion%20don%27t%20seport%20/quiet%20instalation%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/SSIS/vsextensions/MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices/0.1/vspackage)
[image]